# Vuex store state : how to mix the function with variables for reseting state values at single shot

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, nuxt.js, vuex, vuex-modules

I have a `Vuex Store` where I need to reset the variables based on some changes within the application so I am using something like this and everything is working as expected:

```js
const getDefaultState = () => {
    return {
        showModal: false,
        nodeCounter:0,
        nodeInfo: [],
    }
}

export const state = () => getDefaultState()

export const mutations = {
  resetState (state) {
    // Reset all state variables to its default value for next node
    Object.assign(state, getDefaultState())
  },
}
```

However, as per the new requirement, I do not wish to reset the `nodeCounter` and want it to have the incremental value but `reset` all other values so I would like to do something like this:

```js
const getDefaultState = () => {
    return {
        showModal: false,
        nodeInfo: [],
    }
}

export const state = () => {
    nodeCounter:0,
    getDefaultState()
}
```

So all my other values will be `reset` but the `nodeCounter` would be reset only when I refresh the application. But I am unable to achieve this.

Can someone please let me know how can I reset some of the `state` variables and do not reset some of them? I do not wish to reset the state variable one by one so I am using the `function` approach as mentioned in some of the answers here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would try to save the state of nodeCounter (which you want to preserve) and then set it, after you set the state to default. Something like this:

```js
const getDefaultState = () => {
    return {
        showModal: false,
        nodeCounter:0,
        nodeInfo: [],
    }
}

export const state = () => getDefaultState()

export const mutations = {
  resetState (state) {
    // Reset all state variables to its default value for next node
    const tmpNodeCounter = state.nodeCounter;
    state = {...getDefaultState(),nodeCounter: tmpNodeCounter};
  },
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to reset only **some values** in the state with a mutation you do not need to include all state variables in your `resetState` mutation. you could define another object for variables that must be reset each time. here is my Nuxt store file called `change.js`:

```js
const getDefaultState =  {
  showModal: false,
  nodeCounter:0,
  nodeInfo: [],
}

const alwaysReset = {
  showModal: false,
  nodeInfo: [],
}

export const state = () => (getDefaultState);

export const mutations = {
  resetState (state) {
    // Reset state variables that must be reset each time and not all state
    Object.assign(state, alwaysReset);
  },

  increment (state) {
    console.log(state.nodeCounter);
    state.nodeCounter++;
  },

  pushArr (state) {
    console.log(state.nodeInfo);
    state.nodeInfo.push("item");
  }
}
```

The `alwaysReset` object only includes variables that you want to reset each time. other mutations were created to test my answer with this Nuxt page for example:

```html
<template>
  <v-container fluid>
    <v-row>
      <v-col>
        <v-card
          class="pa-2"
          outlined
          tile
        >
          <div>this is a page</div>
          <v-btn @click = "changeState">click</v-btn>
          <v-btn @click = "incrementState">increment</v-btn>
          <v-btn @click = "arrayState">push</v-btn>
        </v-card>
      </v-col>
    </v-row>
  </v-container>
</template>

<script>
  export default {
    methods: {
      changeState: function() {
        this.$store.commit('change/resetState');
      },

      incrementState: function() {
        this.$store.commit('change/increment');
      },

      arrayState: function() {
        this.$store.commit('change/pushArr');
      }
    }
  }
</script>
```

Here I created **3** buttons. one of them resets the specified variables. another one increment the `nodeCounter` to see that with reset this state **does not** change. finally the third one pushes items to `nodeInfo` variable to see that this state will be reset **each** time.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your response. When I used a similar approach within my application its failed for some reason. Not sure why. So I used the approach of keeping track of the variable before resetting and then reassiging.